# What am I doing wrong AJAX autocomplete tagging implementation?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to do something similar to the way tags are added to questions on `S/O` using `php/jquery.`

```
$tagPart = $_POST['tagPart'];
$tagPart = strip_tags($tagPart,"");
$tagPart = trim($tagPart);
$tag_array = explode(',',$tagPart);

$lastTag = end($tag_array);

$part_query = "SELECT title FROM tag WHERE title LIKE '$lastTag%'";

$part_result = mysql_query($part_query) or die($lastTag);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($part_result)){

 echo "<div id ='link' onclick = 'addText(\"".$row['title']."\");'>" . $row['title'] ."</div>";

}
```

This works well for adding the first tag..but doesn't show any results for the second tag after a comma is added...

so if i did PHP, JQuery for example...i would be able to add PHP but upon adding the , and the second tag the SQL query doesn't result in any results...i assume its probably matching the entire string and not just the last tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try outputting your sql statement and check it for errors, extra spaces, etc.

```
$part_query = "SELECT title FROM tag WHERE title LIKE '$lastTag%'";
echo "sql statement: ".$part_query;
```

You trim `$tagPart` but maybe you need to trim `$lastTag` as well:

```
$lastTag = trim(end($tag_array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Does $lastTag have a space in it? For example:

```
$tagPart = 'One, Two, Three';
$tag_array = explode(','$tagPart);
$lastTag = end($tag_array); //$lastTag = ' Three' -> notice the space!
```

I'm not a MySQL expert, so I'm not sure whether "LIKE" would automatically trim this off, but you may want to do $lastTag = trim(end($tag_array)). The fact that the first tag works would make sense if the space is the issue, because the first tag in the list doesn't have a preceding space.